# Trying to encode/decode locations when scraping a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Im trying to scrape a website, and in the url it gets parameters as city and neighborhood. These parameters show in the following encoding:

city for example - %E7%E9%F4%E4
neighborhood for example - %E1%FA+%E2%EC%E9%ED

I tried looking for what this format is and could not find an answer.

Any idea of tools to help me decode/encode this type or what this encoding name even is will be helpful.

Note: Im scraping using python

Edit & more info:
This seems to be because the locations are in hebrew, and a url library is parsig it to make it a valid url. 
Trying to use python to replicate this action I did:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> diction = {"City": "חיפה"}
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode(diction)
```

The output was:

```
'City=%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%94'
```

Which seems like a step in the right direction but still not the same encoding that the website itself uses.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the website details?

Comment: Im affraid they might not like that im scraping their website, So i rather not :/ Srry

Comment: I am afraid i may not be able to help you! Sorry!

Comment: Added more info if it can help. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: You are on the right track. The opposite of `urllib.parse.urlencode` is [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs). Pass it a query string and it will return a dict with all of the data decoded. However, note that it takes an `encoding` argument. You may need to pass in the encoding used by the site to get the correct output. Check the response headers and/or meta tags in the head of the HTML source.

Comment: When passing the url with the encoded data to the "parse_qs" method (%E7%E9%F4%E4 for that matter) I get a dictionary like you said but with '����' as value for the decoded info. The number of these question marks is the correct number of of letters that the hebrew name would have. But still not the actual hebrew name. If I use the library output on the other hand - %D7%97%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%94, I get the right name (חיפה)