# How to print the href attributes using beautifulsoup while automating through selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, webdriverwait

[image: blue element is what i want to access for web scrapping]

Blue element's href value is what i want to access from this HTML

I tried few ways to print the link but didn't work.

My code below:-

```
discover_page = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

finding_accounts = discover_page.find_all("a", class_="author track")
print(len(finding_accounts))

finding_accounts = discover_page.find_all('a[class="author track"]')
print(len(finding_accounts))

accounts = discover_page.select('a', {'class': 'author track'})['href']
print(len(accounts))

Output:- 
0
0
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

URL of the webpage is https://society6.com/discover
but URL changes to https://society6.com/society?show=2 after logging into my account

What am i doing wrong here?

note:- I am using selenium chrome browser here. Answer given here works in my terminal but not when i run the file

My full code:-

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://society6.com/login?done=/")
username = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
username.send_keys("exp4money@gmail.com")
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
password.send_keys("sultan1997")
driver.find_element_by_name('login').click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_link_text('My Society').click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Discover').click()

time.sleep(5)

r = requests.get(driver.current_url)
r.raise_for_status()

'''discover_page = BeautifulSoup(r.html.raw_html, 'html.parser')

finding_accounts = discover_page.find_all("a", class_="author track")
print(len(finding_accounts))

finding_accounts = discover_page.find_all('a[class="author track"]')
print(len(finding_accounts))


links = []
for a in discover_page.find_all('a', class_ = 'author track'): 
        links.append(a['href'])
        #links.append(a.get('href'))

print(links)'''

#discover_page.find_all('a')

links = []
for a in discover_page.find_all("a", attrs = {"class": "author track"}): 
        links.append(a['href'])
        #links.append(a.get('href'))

print(links)

#soup.find_all("a", attrs = {"class": "author track"})'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
a_tags = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "author track"})

for a in soup.find_all('a',{'class':'author track'}):
    print('https://society6.com'+a['href'])
```

codes in documentation is the one I was using experimenting with

Comment: That's now how select works - it needs a CSS selector... does `discover_page.select('a.author.track')` work for you? Although - that should be equal to your first attempt with `.find_all` which returns nothing.

Comment: You should also check the original page source as it's returned from the site and not the DOM in the dev tools after javascript etc... may have manipulated the DOM to check that element actually exists to be seen by the parser.

Comment: a.author.track didn't work. I checked the page source and the element exist.

Comment: Does `discover_page.select('a')` return *anything*? It might be the builtin `html.parser` isn't able to (for whatever reason - it's not particularly robust) correctly parse the source... In that case you'll have to use the `lxml` or `html5lib` options instead.

Comment: yea it returns value for all links in 'a' except when i put class in it, i think the problem is in parser. I tried to put 'lxml' instead of 'html.parser' but showed error, how do i add a new parser?

Comment: Just install `lxml` as you would any other library on pypi... using pip or downloading an installer for it.

Comment: Can you give us the url? The page might be JavaScript rendered.

Comment: @jxpython url is - https://society6.com/discover

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to find all links without trying it manually in Beautifulsoup. Then go for **[requests-html](https://html.python-requests.org/)**

Sample code to grab all links,

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://society6.com/discover'
session = HTMLSession(mock_browser=True)
r = session.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

print(r.html.links)
print(r.html.absolute_links)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.raw_html, 'html.parser')
a_tags = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "author track"})
for a_tag in a_tags:
    print(a_tag['href'])
```

Comment: thanks but i get this error when using the bottom code link:- AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'html'. requests_html also seems interesting

Comment: what is your python version?

Comment: python version is 3.7.0

Comment: `finding_accounts = discover_page.find_all("a", class_="author track")
print(len(finding_accounts))` is working fine and I am getting total count = 40

Comment: oh, actually its working fine in my terminal also. I am using selenium chrome browser since I had to log into my account. Could selenium be the problem?

Comment: This is not the right usage `accounts = discover_page.select('a', {'class': 'author track'})['href']
print(len(accounts))` Check the doc - https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: cool, will remove that. I was just experimenting with different ways to do it. Any other problem in the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get('https://society6.com/discover')
soup_data = BeautifulSoup(data.content, "lxml")

for a in soup_data.find_all('a',{'class':'author track'}):
    print('https://society6.com'+a['href'])
```

Comment: It worked in my terminal. but when I run the file then it doesn't work. few codes before i added from your code - r = requests.get(driver.current_url)
r.raise_for_status() and some import statements - from selenium import webdriver
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

Answer (score 0):

As per your question to print the `href` from the desired elements you can use only **Selenium** using the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
  options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\ChromeDriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://society6.com/login?done=/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#email"))).send_keys("exp4money@gmail.com")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#password").send_keys("sultan1997")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[name='login']").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#nav-user-my-society>span"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Discover"))).click()
  hrefs_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.author.track")))
  for element in hrefs_elements:
      print(element.get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  https://society6.com/pivivikstrm
  https://society6.com/cafelab
  https://society6.com/cafelab
  https://society6.com/colorandcolor
  https://society6.com/83oranges
  https://society6.com/aftrdrk
  https://society6.com/alaskanmommabear
  https://society6.com/thindesign
  https://society6.com/colorandcolor
  https://society6.com/aftrdrk
  https://society6.com/aljahorvat
  https://society6.com/bribuckley
  https://society6.com/hennkim
  https://society6.com/franciscomffonseca
  https://society6.com/83oranges
  https://society6.com/nadja1
  https://society6.com/beeple
  https://society6.com/absentisdesigns
  https://society6.com/alexandratarasoff
  https://society6.com/artdekay880
  https://society6.com/annaki
  https://society6.com/cafelab
  https://society6.com/bribuckley
  https://society6.com/bitart
  https://society6.com/draw4you
  https://society6.com/cafelab
  https://society6.com/beeple
  https://society6.com/burcukorkmazyurek
  https://society6.com/absentisdesigns
  https://society6.com/deanng
  https://society6.com/beautifulhomes
  https://society6.com/aftrdrk
  https://society6.com/printsproject
  https://society6.com/bluelela
  https://society6.com/anipani
  https://society6.com/ecmazur
  https://society6.com/batkei
  https://society6.com/menchulica
  https://society6.com/83oranges
  https://society6.com/7115
  ```