# Unable to access webpage with request in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

After some discussion with my problem on [Unable to print links using beautifulsoup while automating through selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52345850/unable-to-print-links-using-beautifulsoup-while-automating-through-selenium/52351581?noredirect=1#comment91648781_52351581)

I realized that the main problem is in the URL which the request is not able to extract. URL of the page is actually https://society6.com/discover but I am using selenium to log into my account so the URL becomes https://society6.com/society?show=2

However, I can't use the second URL with request since its showing error. How do i scrap information from URL like this.

Comment: you must log in with request too

Comment: how to do that? plz link to any sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to log in first!

To do that you can use the `bs4.BeautifulSoup` library.

Here is an implementation that I have used:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE_URL = "https://society6.com/"


def log_in_and_get_session():
    """
    Get the session object with login details
    :return: requests.Session
    """    
    ss = requests.Session()
    ss.verify = False    # optinal for uncertifaied sites. 
    text = ss.get(f"{BASE_URL}login").text
    csrf_token = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser").input["value"]
    data = {"username": "your_username", "password": "your_password", "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf_token}
    # results = ss.post("{}login".format(BASE_URL), data=data)
    results = ss.post("{}login".format(BASE_URL), data=data)
    if results.ok:
        print("Login success", results.status_code)
        return ss
    else:
        print("Can't  login", results.status_code)
```

Using the 'post` method to log in...

Hope this helps you!

**Edit**

Added the beginning of the function.

Comment: thanks, but 'return ss' code line is showing error - E0104: Return outside function

Comment: Cool! It worked. But i got a warning - 'InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised'. Is it something to worry about?

Comment: you can mark out the line: `ss.verify = False` that will take care of that.

Comment: @SultanMorbiwala let me know if canceling `verify` helped you! happy to help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180150/discussion-between-moshe-slavin-and-sultan-morbiwala).