# Pulling the href from a link when web scraping using Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am scraping from this page: https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2018/week_1.htm

It is a list of game scores for American Football. I want to open the link to the stats for the first game. The text displayed for said says "Final". My code so far...

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


#assigning url
my_url = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2018/week_1.htm"

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
raw_page = uReq(my_url)
page_html = raw_page.read()
raw_page.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")

#find all games on page
games = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"game_summary expanded nohover"})

link = games[0].find("td",{"class":"right gamelink"})
print(link)
```

When I run this i receive the following output...

```
<a href="/boxscores/201809060phi.htm">Final</a>
```

How do I assign only the link text (i.e. "/boxscores/201809060phi.htm") to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
link = games[0].find("td",{"class":"right gamelink"}).find('a')

print(link['href'])
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!