# Unable to print links in another function

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I've written some code in `php` to scrape some preferable links out of the main page of wikipedia. When I execute my script, the links are coming through accordingly.

However, at this point I've defined two functions within my script in order to learn how to pass links from one function to another. Now, my goal is to print the links in the latter function but it only prints the first link and nothing else.

If I use only this function `fetch_wiki_links()`, I can get several links but when i try to print the same within `get_links_in_ano_func()` then it prints the first link only.

How can I get them all even when I use the second function?

This is what I've written so far:

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$prefix = "https://en.wikipedia.org";
function fetch_wiki_links($prefix)
{
    $weblink = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page";
    $htmldoc   = file_get_html($weblink);
    foreach ($htmldoc->find("a[href^='/wiki/']") as $a) {
        $links          = $a->href . '<br>';
        $absolute_links = $prefix . $links;
        return $absolute_links;
    }
}
function get_links_in_ano_func($absolute_links)
{
    echo $absolute_links;
}
$items = fetch_wiki_links($prefix);
get_links_in_ano_func($items);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function returned the value at the very first iteration. You will need something like this:

```
function fetch_wiki_links($prefix)
{
    $weblink = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page";
    $htmldoc   = file_get_html($weblink);
    $absolute_links = array();
    foreach ($htmldoc->find("a[href^='/wiki/']") as $a) {
        $links          = $a->href . '<br>';
        $absolute_links []= $prefix . $links;
    }
    return implode("\n", $absolute_links);
}
```