# Trouble fetching some title from a webpage

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, domdocument

I've written a script in php to scrape a ***title*** visible as ***hair fall shamboo*** from a webpage. When I execute my below script, I get the following error:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'nodeValue' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\runcode\testfile.php on line 16.

[Link to that site](https://www.purplle.com/search?q=hair%20fall%20shamboo)

Script I've tried with:

```
<?php
    function get_content($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_exec($ch);
        $htmlContent = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $htmlContent;
    }
    $link = "https://www.purplle.com/search?q=hair%20fall%20shamboo"; 
    $xml = get_content($link);
    $dom = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($xml);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $title = $xpath->query('//h1[@class="br-hdng"]/span')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo "{$title}";
?>
```

My expected output is:

```
hair fall shamboo
```

Although the `xpath` I used within my above script seems to be correct, I pasted here the relevant portion of html elements within which the `title` can be found:

```
<h1 _ngcontent-c0="" class="br-hdng"><span _ngcontent-c0="" class="pr dib">hair fall shamboo<!----></span></h1>
```

***PostScript:*** The `title` I wish to parse gets loaded dynamically. As I'm new to php I don't understand whether the way I tried is accurate. If not what I should do then?

> ***The following are the scripts I've created using two different languages and found them working like magic.***

I got success using `javascript`:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
function run () {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto("https://www.purplle.com/search?q=hair%20fall%20shamboo");
            let urls = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let items = document.querySelector('h1.br-hdng span');
            return items.innerText;;
            })
            browser.close();
            return resolve(urls);
        } catch (e) {
            return reject(e);
        }
    })
}
run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Again, I got success using `python`:

```
import requests_html

with requests_html.HTMLSession() as session:
    r = session.get('https://www.purplle.com/search?q=hair%20fall%20shamboo')
    r.html.render()
    item = r.html.find("h1.br-hdng span",first=True).text
    print(item)
```

***What's wrong with `php` then?***

Comment: `$xml = get_content($link);` maybe here you wish to use `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: Your suggested change brought about the same error @user9741470.

Comment: If the content is not in the HTML then you can't get it by parsing the HTML.

Comment: @Topto You know what the problem is: dynamic content. `CURL` doesn't run Js, but you could try `php-phantomjs`, however I can't recommend it as I've never used it. PHP is a great server-side language, but not that good at web-scraping. If you plan to use it for web-scraping, I think you should stick to a general purpose language such as Python, Ruby, etc.

Comment: Your information is always my top preference @t.m.adam. You saved me a lot of time from digging deep into it. However, you didn't mention `node.js` in your list. How about that for my purpose? Much obliged.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you could include Node.Js in this category. I've never used `puppeteer`, but it looks good, so if you feel comfortable with it then sure, Node is fine. Cheers!

Comment: If by *dynamically* you mean after DOM being loaded then you can't do it with PHP.

Comment: It seems the title isn't dynamic, its what you are actually sending in **q** parameter. e.g. [link](https://www.purplle.com/search?q=hair%20fall%20shambooLetsTest) Also i agree to @t.m.adam regarding CURL does not run js.

Comment: @karanthakkar Well, technically that is still dynamic content, but possibly created from the back-end script instead of JavaScript. I think the OP is not interested in this specific element, they just want to learn how to scrape dynamic content with PHP. If that is the case, the `php-phantomjs` library should do it, but I have no experience with it so I will not post an answer.

Comment: You can always read the mind @t.m.adam.

Comment: @SIM You know, great minds think alike:)

Answer (score 7):

It could very well be that there are more issues with your code than I have covered in this answer, but the most prominent issue that I see is the following:

[`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) is not a static method, but an instance method (which returns a boolean). You should first create an instance of `DOMDocument` and then call `loadHTML()` on that instance:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($xml);
```

However, since you have suppressed errors with the `@` operator on that particular line, you are not receiving a warning about this. And although it's very commonly seen that the error suppressor operator `@` is used to suppress HTML validation errors, like this, you should look into using [`libxml_use_internal_errors()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php)<sup>1</sup> instead, as this does not suppress general PHP errors.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$oldSetting = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($xml);
libxml_use_internal_errors($oldSetting);
```

As a final note:
It's possible to load a DOM document from a URL directly (without the need for `cURL`) with [`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php), if your PHP installation is configured to allow loading of URLs via the configuration setting [`allow_url_fopen`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen). Be aware though that this setting is often disabled for security reasons, so use it with care, if you plan on using it.

---

Here's a simple test-case which should work as expected:

```php
<?php

$html = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>DOMDocument test-case</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dummy-container">
    <h1 _ngcontent-c0="" class="br-hdng"><span _ngcontent-c0="" class="pr dib">hair fall shamboo<!----></span></h1>
  </div>
</body>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$oldSetting = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
libxml_use_internal_errors($oldSetting);

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$title = $xpath->query( '//h1[@class="br-hdng"]/span' )->item( 0 )->nodeValue;
echo $title;
```

<sup>[See this example interpreted online on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2fCTT)</sup>

You should replace the contents of `$html` with the output of your `get_content()` call. If it doesn't work, then either:

1. there's something wrong with fetching the HTML with `cURL` (do `var_dump( $html );` before loading into `DOMDocument`, for instance, to see the contents you retrieved), or...
2. perhaps you are working inside a namespace, in which case you should prepend a backslash before `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`, i.e.: `new \DOMDocument;` and `new \DOMXPath( $dom );`.

---

<sup>1. LibXML is the XML library that is used by DOMDocument to parse XML/HTML documents.</sup>

Comment: I did try with your suggested options and finally came up with the same error I was having in the first place with my existing script @Decent Dabbler. Are you sure there is still any option to get that title? I'm really fed up with php.

Comment: @Topto I've updated my answer with a working example, which you can test yourself and also view interpreted online. Make the necessary adjustments and see if it works now.

Comment: You are dealing with static content @Decent Dabbler whereas the one I wanna parse from the real web is a dynamic content which gets loaded few seconds later when you open that page. This is where the problem arises. Btw, I tried all possible combinations but no dice.

Comment: @Topto I see... I didn't realise that (I tend to not click unfamiliar links in questions to view their content; my bad). `DOMDocument` can't deal with dynamic content, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

> What's wrong with php then?

php doesn't run javascript. presumably, `puppeteer` from your javascript code, as well as requests_html from your python code, both run javascript.

your problem is that this page loads the `br-hdng` title & products with javascript, it's not part of the HTML at all. it's all actually loaded from `https://www.purplle.com/api/shop/itemsv3` , with a bunch of GET parameters, . you need to do JSON parsing here, not HTML parsing :)  but before you can access that api, you need cookies given by the search page, and *the search string must match the api search string* (otherwise the api will just return errors), check this:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 0);
header ( "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8" );
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => '', // enables cookie handling without saving them anywhere. this page requires cookie handling.
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0', // 'libcurl/? PHP/' . PHP_VERSION, // many websites block requests without a useragent
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1 
) );
// we don't care what's on this page, we just need to fetch it to create a cookie session.
$search_query = 'hair fall shamboo';
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.purplle.com/search?q=' . rawurlencode ( $search_query ) );
curL_exec ( $ch );
$url = 'https://www.purplle.com/api/shop/itemsv3?' . http_build_query ( array (
        'list_type' => 'search',
        'custom' => '',
        'list_type_value' => $search_query,
        'page' => '1',
        'sort_by' => 'rel',
        'elite' => '0' 
) );
// $url = 'https://www.purplle.com/api/shop/itemsv3?list_type=search&custom=&list_type_value=hair%20fall%20shamboo&page=1&sort_by=rel&elite=0';
// $out = tmpfile ();
// curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
// CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
// 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
// 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
// 'Referer: https://www.purplle.com/search?q=hair%20fall%20shamboo',
// // Cookie: __cfduid=d3199415b5ce18cbff2779802b1f843331544901552; csrftoken=f8f18b5deae92972f63343e13c6a460b; purpllesession=hedxkc%2FkdGye%2BYi6ebmJktUN1LeqA5rdVXu96%2F0j0yqtP2xZ8LfwpK8daXqPSkeZulO9ZvqpMYXTmY8oMD03VcG9vdKGBm30R9fU%2FQygtXBFhZvfvsu0scyaL3FqHbePp2zG45MevWU961eg82KAkCuHk0qFM8URQBRyYV5gg8TeqnTPgI3tF87H5nJ%2BmfO4pn%2BRWmIuWXvgNXAO%2F8GEaH6lJVl17QZm9c5vwi10OYeLfmSdIMy6V2Pp0ZjLTzuFw2de5jpR0zsbHHKZ0C2e548PiDl3taHIE5wuZO4HYIeXUqTpE98%2Fo3kztoU1bTlXGZgu%2FxVQ3EWLRFWQ2t57UawA%2FuERlD8vvOyFGbYHGAWVxgFTR%2FObAhFLHns5kqoj; _autm30d=null; visitorppl=NZ5tqQpGlFYWg2MrDl1302113161544901552; session_initiated=Direct; _tmpsess=1; token=desktop_5c1553b07c61c_7955_16122018; __uzma=5c1553b085a480.63440826; __uzmb=1544901552; __uzmc=632121030774; __uzmd=1544901552
// 'Connection: keep-alive'
// ),
// // CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO=>array('www.purplle.com:443:dumpinput.ratma.net:80'),
// CURLOPT_STDERR => $out,
// CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1
// ) );
// var_dump ( $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
$json = curl_exec ( $ch );
$data = json_decode ( $json, true );

// var_dump ($json, $data );
$title = $data ['list_title'];
echo 'title: ' . $title . "\n";
foreach ( $data ['items'] as $item ) {
    echo "name: ", $item ['name'], "\n";
}
```

output:

```
title: hair fall shamboo
name: VLCC Hair fall Shampoo 350 ML (Buy1 Get1) & Ayurveda Hair Oil Combo (470 ml)
name: Biotique Bio Kelp Protein Shampoo For Falling Hair (190 ml)
name: Biotique Fresh Texture Shampoo - Bio Henna Leaf (120 ml)
name: Good Vibes Scalp Purifying Shampoo -Neem And Aloe Vera (200 ml)
name: Khadi Shikakai Sat Hair Cleanser Scalp Therapy (210 ml) By Swati Gramodyog
name: Good Vibes Apple Cider Vinegar Shampoo (120 ml)
name: Good Vibes Refreshing Shampoo - Green Apple (200 ml)
name: Good Vibes Hydrating Shampoo -Marigold (200 ml)
name: Alps Goodness Smoothening Shampoo - Keratin (50 ml)
name: Alps Goodness Softening Shampoo - Coconut & Almond (50 ml)
name: Alps Goodness Split End Control Shampoo - Coconut, Garlic & Shea Butter (50 ml)
name: Passion Indulge Papain Shampoo & Conditioner For Soft & Shiny Hair (200 ml + 100 ml)
name: Good Vibes Apple Cider Vinegar Shampoo (200 ml)
name: Alps Goodness Split End Control Shampoo - Coconut, Garlic & Shea Butter (200 ml)
name: Alps Goodness Nourishing Shampoo - Argan Oil & Olive (200 ml)
name: Alps Goodness Moisturizing Shampoo - Ginger & Egg (200 ml)
name: Alps Goodness Conditioning Shampoo - Pure Honey (200 ml)
name: Alps Goodness Hydrating Shampoo - Tea Tree (200 ml)
name: Alps Goodness Smoothening Shampoo - Keratin (200 ml)
name: Alps Goodness Softening Shampoo - Coconut & Almond (200 ml)
name: Good Vibes Scalp Purifying Shampoo -Neem And Aloe Vera (120 ml)
name: Good Vibes Hydrating Shampoo - Marigold (120 ml)
name: Alps Goodness Conditioning Shampoo - Pure Honey (50 ml)
name: Alps Goodness Moisturizing Shampoo - Ginger & Egg (50 ml)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @hanshenrik. The data of that site is totally useless to me. All I wanted to know how can I grab javascript encrypted items from a webpage as few of them do not provide any api neither any json laden link generated through dev tools. The bottom line is I wanna grab the title sticking to the URL in the post no matter if any browser simulator comes into play to accomplish the task. There are already two demos out there from two different languages making use of the main link.

Comment: @asmitu the title of that page as presented to search engines is actually `Purplle.com: Buy Cosmetic Products & Beauty Products Online In India`, which you get from inspecting `<meta property="og:title"` , is that the title you want?  in which case the xpath would be `//meta[@property="og:title"]`